# Symfony2 / Twig - Error Message: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying render an array on my page with Twig, but always I get the following error code:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\JPP\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 10098") in ProfileBundle:Profile:profile.html.twig at line 228.

When I look at profile.html.twig i see the following for-loop:

```
                    `{% for Educations in Education|sortByDate %}
                    <div id="education{{loop.index0}}">                               
                            <tr>
                                <td class="border">{{ Educations.fromDate|date('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="border">{{ Educations.toDate|date('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>                                    
                                <td class="border">{{ Educations.company }}</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="border" id="jobsChar{{loop.index0}}">{{ Educations.jobs }}</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="border"><input type="button" title="Show Details" class="showDetails"  id="details_show{{loop.index0}}"/><input type="button" title="Edit" class="editJob" id="education_edit{{loop.index0}}" /><form style="display:inline" action="../deleteJob" id="deleteJob"><input type="button" title="Delete Job" class="deleteJob" id="job_delete{{loop.index0}}" /></form></td>
                            </tr></div>{% endfor %}`
```

In the following you can see the array which should be processed by the for-loop of TWIG, but without success...

array(5) { [0]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(80) ["userId"]=> int(3) ["company"]=> string(24) "Solothurner Spitäler AG" ["jobArea"]=> int(0) ["subJobsArea"]=> int(0) ["jobs"]=> int(2) ["jobLabel"]=> string(8) "Förster" ["fromDate"]=> object(DateTime)#437 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2010-01-01 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } ["toDate"]=> object(DateTime)#436 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2011-02-09 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } } [1]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(87) ["userId"]=> int(3) ["company"]=> string(6) "TOP IT" ["jobArea"]=> int(0) ["subJobsArea"]=> int(0) ["jobs"]=> int(3) ["jobLabel"]=> string(20) "Dipl. Pflegefachfrau" ["fromDate"]=> object(DateTime)#433 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2008-05-01 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } ["toDate"]=> object(DateTime)#432 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2009-05-22 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } } [2]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(103) ["userId"]=> int(3) ["company"]=> string(10) "Helsana AG" ["jobArea"]=> int(0) ["subJobsArea"]=> int(0) ["jobs"]=> int(1) ["jobLabel"]=> string(11) "Holffäller" ["fromDate"]=> object(DateTime)#430 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-01 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } ["toDate"]=> object(DateTime)#429 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-01 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } } [3]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(104) ["userId"]=> int(3) ["company"]=> string(8) "ALPIQ AG" ["jobArea"]=> int(0) ["subJobsArea"]=> int(0) ["jobs"]=> int(2) ["jobLabel"]=> string(8) "Förster" ["fromDate"]=> object(DateTime)#427 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-01 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } ["toDate"]=> object(DateTime)#426 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-09 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } } [4]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(130) ["userId"]=> int(3) ["company"]=> string(8) "ALPIQ AG" ["jobArea"]=> int(0) ["subJobsArea"]=> int(0) ["jobs"]=> int(2) ["jobLabel"]=> string(8) "Förster" ["fromDate"]=> object(DateTime)#424 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-01 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } ["toDate"]=> object(DateTime)#439 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-05-09 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } } }

Please can you help me? Thank you very much.

Cheers Roger

Comment: which line exactly is 228 ? and where did you dump the array? in the controller or in the template?

Comment: It's possible that the error is in your sortByDate filter. Can you post the code ?

Comment: @Mohammad: {% for Educations in Education|sortByDate %} is line 228. Sorry I forget to mention the lines!

Comment: @Webberig: I created the sortByDate filter by my own. Here is the code:/**
*
*Sorts an array.
*
*@param array $a An array
*/
function twig_sortByDate_filter($a)
{
    usort($a, "datumsvergleich");

    return $a;
}

function datumsvergleich( $a, $b )
{
    if ( $a->fromDate == $b->fromDate )
        return 0;
    if ( $a->fromDate < $b->fromDate )
        return 1;
    return -1;
}

Comment: Can you do var_dump($a) at the end of the twig function (before the return line though) ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Twig will try to escape returned data from filters. It's possible that Twig doesn't expect the return result to be an array and break it. Try setting "is_safe" to true when defining your Twig filter.

If that doesn't work, I doubt you can use a filter like that. Filters are generally used for text manipulation, not complex data. You could try definining a function instead of a filter, or in worst case process your data where you should => the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't in twig, add a line in the beginning `{{ dump(Educations) }}` and I'm sure it will return null.
The problem is in the controller, you said you dump it and it worked, but I'm assuming you dumped it in the controller, can you please add the action code or the last few lines of it so see how exactly you are passing the variable to the template.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to remove the " |sortByDate "